# Why does the reopen link use the browser's inbuilt confirm feature?

Tags: discussion, design

When you click the reopen link on a closed question, you get a confirm box driven by the browser:

[image]

It seems a bit jarring to see, compared to the rest of the site design.  Is there a reason for using this, other than perhaps it's a little used feature so isn't high on the list of things to spend time creating a "proper" dialog for?

Comment: I guess this was the easiest and fastest way to accomplish a confirmation. I agree a styled `dialog` window would be a lot neater indeed! :)

Comment: That's not the only place it happens - see also adding a second answer to a question you've already answered, undoing upvotes on comments or deleting comments, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I'd forgotten that one (adding additional answers) - another area that I suspect is not used very often, but is certainly open to a wider audience.  Now you mention deleting comments, that is something I do a lot, but for some reason that one feels natural so it didn't come to mind.  Huh, weird.

Comment: Not to mention flagging VLQ from H&I queue.

Comment: Deleting and undeleting posts is the same way.

Comment: Simple answer, the time it would take to customize all these confirmation dialogs is much more than what they can be using out of the box.  Its very low priority...if it even is a priority.  Although the dialog could look like the site, you'd be running into the same functionality...and for what?  If it aint broken dont bother fixing it!

Comment: It's also more mobile-friendly. JS modals and little screens don't play well together

Comment: Why complicate things ? This solution works just fine and looks okay. The extra design improvement by using a custom modal aren't worth the effort (and will break on small screens).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using the browser dialog is the correct approach.

Using an HTML overlay is, as Raeffaele commented, unfriendly to small and/or low resolution devices.  It's also unfriendly to screen readers and accessibility, and in general disrespectful to user control over their own browsing experience.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers - I can see why it's more than just a "it's not high on the priority list".  This may have been a candidate for UX, now I'm thinking about it - perhaps it's already been covered over there...! Edit - [Indeed it has](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64793/native-confirmation-dialog-js-or-something-else)

Answer (score 12):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this. Browsers provide a popup confirmation feature. Why not use it? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: No one really even thought twice about it until Chrome moved everyone's cheese to the top center of the screen. That was the only remotely serious reason to consider something custom, and not really compelling enough to implement anything different.